# List of features and layers based on edit date in ArcMap

Tags: arcmap, excel

I regularly update our GIS data using ArcMap to improve its accuracy, and due to our schema this involves editing multiple features across multiple layers.

Is there a way to extract a list of the updated features across multiple layers and export the list as say a spreadsheet?

The reason is that after I edit the data, other users need to update other aspects of our system to match as this is not done automatically (eg asset management software). Ideally I would obtain a spreadsheet that comprised the following columns:

- Layer Name
- OBJECTID
- Attributes changed (not essential, but wishlist)

The feature tables generally include an OBJECTID and last edited date and time.  Ideally I could generate a list for all edits on a given day and user

[image]

Comment: What is your linking fields between your GIS and AMS?  I would have thought it would be your `AssetID` field (from your screenshot) but these are all blank.  Beware using `ObjectID` for this purpose

Comment: What AMS are you using?  Have you considered linking the two and performing both updates simultaneously? Spatial assets, and linking GIS and AMS databases is of great interest to me (sad as that may sound)

Comment: Coming back to your question - do you use Replication and/or Archiving?  I think one or both of those may offer options

Comment: Editor Tracking will populate timestamps and other properties based on edit events. You'd still need to walk the list of feature classes to harvest this information.

Comment: AssetID is ultimately the link between the AMS and GIS. However to create new assets, I enter the data into GIS as our AMS doesn't include a spatial component (note I don't choose what software weuse).  Once it is entered in the AMS it is given an AssetID.  The screenshot below doesn't show it, but there would be assets with AssetID, and I adjust these spatially in GIS - if there is updated attribute information, our GIS person does this manually at present.